# SQL Query to select top 2 for each value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns, the data in column1 has repeating values and column 3 has totals, what I'd like to do is to return the top 2 totals for each value in column 1.

My query to create this table is below:

```
SELECT service,name, total
  FROM [test].[dbo].[TestTable]
  join test1.dbo.service
  on substring(servan,0,4)=servicebn
  where substring(servan,0,4)=servicebn and name <> testname
group by service,name,total
order by service,total desc
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `SQL Server 2005+`, you can use *Common Table Expression* and *Window Function*.

```
WITH recordsList
AS
(
    SELECT  service, name, total,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY service 
                                ORDER BY total DESC) rn
    FROM    [test].[dbo].[TestTable]
            INNER join test1.dbo.servd
                on substring(servan,0,4)=servicebn
    where   substring(servan,0,4) = servicebn and 
            name <> testname
)
SELECT  service, name, total
FROM    recordsLIst
WHERE   rn <= 2
```

As a side note, this query has poor in performance because it requires `FULL TABLE SCAN` on every table. The reason is because of the join condition `substring(servan,0,4)=servicebn`. It doesn't use index.

Comment: Thanks JW, with regards to the join, how should it be to maximise performance?

Comment: do not use `function` around the values. create another column which is the same with the value of `substring(servan,0,4)` and define an index on it. use that new column to join against `servicebn`